# input[data-field=""] access via JQuery possible?

Tags: jquery

i have a HTML button which looks like this one:

```
<input type="button" name="btn_recommend" data-postid="127" value="Recommend (4)" onclick="a2m.recommend.add();">
```

Is it possible to access this button via JQuery as follows?

`$('input[data-postid="127"]').val()`;

? This is not working currently...

Thanks!

Comment: Works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ecmHa/

Comment: Works for me as well: http://jsbin.com/ihiqez/2/edit

Comment: how did you implement the above code?